# Prob. 29, Chap. 2, in Baby Rudin, 3rd ed: Every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is the union of at most countable collection of disjoint open intervals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

Here is Prob. 29, Chap. 2, in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by  Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> Prove that every open set in $\mathbb{R}^1$ is the union of an at most countable collection of disjoint segments.

How to give this proof?

My effort:

> Let $E$ be a non-empty open subset of $\mathbb{R}^1$, and let $p \in E$. Then we can find a real number $\delta > 0$ such that 
>   $$(\, p-\delta \, , \, p+\delta \, ) \subset E.$$ 
>   Now we can find rational numbers $q_1$, $q_2$ such that 
>   $$p-\delta < q_1 < p < q_2 < p+\delta.$$ 
>   So we have
>   $$ \left( q_1, q_2 \right) \subset (\, p-\delta \, , \, p+\delta \, ) \subset E.$$
>   In this way, we can show that 
>   $$E = \cup (q_1, q_2),$$
>   and this union is of course that of a countable collection of segments.

Now how to show that these intervals are disjoint?

Is this line of reasoning going to lead to our desired conclusion?

Comment: If $E=\cup_i (p_i,q_i)$, $p_i,q_i\in \mathbb{Q}$, then you can use induction. Define $J_1 = (p_1,q_1)$, and $J_2 = (p_2,q_2)-J_1$. Proceed by induction, $J_{n+1} = I_{n+1}-J_n$.

Answer (score 7):

The intervals as you've defined them won't generally be disjoint. You could try the following: for each $x \in E$ define $a_x = \inf\{a : [a,x] \subset E\}$ and $b_x = \sup\{b : [x,b] \subset E\}$. $a_x$ is possibly $-\infty$ and $b_x$ is possibly $\infty$. Show that 1) if $x \in E$ then $(a_x,b_x) \subset E$, and 2) if $x,y \in E$ then $(a_x,b_x) = (a_y,b_y)$ or $(a_x,b_x) \cap (a_y,b_y) = \emptyset$. Since each open interval contains a rational number there are at most countably many distinct intervals $(a_x,b_x)$, they are pairwise disjoint, and $\displaystyle E = \bigcup_{x \in E} (a_x,b_x)$.

Comment: P, how to show that if $x \in E$, $y \in E$, then either $(a_x, b_x) = (a_y, b_y)$ or $(a_x,b_x) \cap (a_y,b_y) = \emptyset$?

Comment: @UmbertoP Can you explain how to show $2)$? It makes sense intuitively, I'm just not sure how I would go about proving it.

Comment: $ (a_x, b_x) = (a_y, b_y)$ IFF $[x, y] \subset E$. Then if not $(a_x, b_x) = (a_y, b_y)$, then $\exists z \in [x, y]$ that is not in $E$. Thus $(a_x, b_x) \cap (a_y, b_y)$ is empty. @SaaqibMahmood